# Reading data from infowindow in Cartoons?

Tags: carto, infowindow

Is there a way to read data from a CartoDB infowindow and write it, e.g. into a form?

**For example:** In a city plan with parcels, the user clicks on a parcel and the infowindow opens with information on this parcel. Now I think about a “Fill in” button that allows writing the attributes of the parcel selected into a form.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've prepared an example for you. You can check it [here](http://bl.ocks.org/xatpy/f9cdabd598800538d9c2) (and [full page](http://bl.ocks.org/Xatpy/raw/f9cdabd598800538d9c2/))

The "trick" is to **capture the infowindow's data**. *Infowindow* is a [**Backbone Model**](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/), so I worked with its *bind* method.

```
.done(function(vis, layers) {
      lyr = layers[1];
      lyr.infowindow.bind('change', function() {
        if ((lyr.infowindow.attributes.content.fields !== undefined) && (lyr.infowindow.attributes.content.fields[4] !== undefined)) {
          country = lyr.infowindow.attributes.content.fields[4].value;
          pop2005 = lyr.infowindow.attributes.content.fields[7].value;
          document.getElementById("inpCountry").value = country;
          document.getElementById("inpPop").value = pop2005;
        }
      });
    })
```

Also, in this example, I'm filling a form with data, as you requested in your post.

Comment: Great example! Muchas gracias!